# Optimising multiple stacked for loops

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct

I am currently refactoring an old program and I am having trouble with finding a way to optimize a certain piece of code.

The primary aim is memory usage reduction over performance as the system is embedded.

```
for(n = 0; n < NUMBER_VARS_IN_STRUCT1; n++) {
                        int m;
                        for(m = 0; m < NUMBER_OF_LANGUAGES; m++) {
                            UnicodeStrCat(2, tx_data_1, struct1.var1[n][m], L"\r\n");
                            SendSerialUserData(UNICODE);
                        }
                        for(m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
                            sprintf(ansicode_text, "%.8f\r\n", (double) struct1.var2[n][m]);
                            StrAnsiToUnicode(tx_data_1, ansicode_text);
                            SendSerialUserData(UNICODE);
                        }
                        for(m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
                            sprintf(ansicode_text, "%.8f\r\n", (double) struct1.var3[n][m]);
                            StrAnsiToUnicode(tx_data_1, ansicode_text);
                            SendSerialUserData(UNICODE);
                        }
```

The code is much longer (~250 lines of the same sort of thing) and is then repeated in a similar manner for allowing data to be read back in to the device.

I had thought that a solution to reduce memory usage would be to potentially hardcode an array to hold pointers to each of the array values in each structure (Or if I know the size of each array then I could increment the pointer location), and then largely reduce the code size by simply cycling through this.

The output of the function is to print out a large table of data through a serial bus.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: The solution you propose looks good to me.

Comment: Which memory do you want to reduce, data or instructions?

Comment: I would like to reduce data memory, but I had thought that by using const it would save instruction memory without really adding to the data memory.